# Clearing a specific definition

Tags: assignment

Consider the case where a symbol has multiple definitions attached to it,

```
a /: Subscript[a,2] := 1
a[b_] := 2
a[b_, c_] := 3
```

How does one clear (/unset/remove) only one of those definitions while leaving the others intact?

Comment: `=.` works nicely for removing any of the last two definitions. You need `TagUnset[]` to remove the first one.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `Unset` for this, like so:

```
a[b_, c_] =.
```

`=.` works with `UpValues` too (the full form of this has `TagUnset`):

```
a /: Subscript[a,2] =.
```

You need to use the same pattern in `Unset` that you used in the definition.  Get this using `Information` (i.e. `?a`).

Answer (score 16):

You can use `Unset` or `=.` to remove a single definition. For example, for your above function its `DownValues` are

```
DownValues@a
Out[1]= {HoldPattern[a[b_]] :> 2, HoldPattern[a[b_, c_]] :> 3}
```

Unsetting the definition for `a[b_, c_]`,

```
a[b_, c_] =.
DownValues@a
Out[2]= {HoldPattern[a[b_]] :> 2}
```

It works similarly for `UpValues` too, i.e., you can do `a /: Subscript[a,2]=.` to clear that particular `UpValue`