# How to export/import function values

Tags: functions, export, import, list-manipulation

I have a function with two variables:

```
f[x_,y_]:=f[x,y] = ...
```

I calculated some values (they are fractions like 435345345/3424242424) and would like to store the values from x=1 to x=5000 with y=0 in a file, so that I can use them later again in a function g[x]

I exported them:

```
Export["file.dat", Table[f[x,0],{x,1,5000}]
```

And then I import them in another file:

```
data = Import["file.dat", "List"]
```

Now I can access the fractions in data by using, for example:

```
ToExpression[data[[7]]]
```

Which gives me the fraction that was originally stored in f[7,0]

So far so good, but I would again like to have the values stored in some function g, with the properties that (in new file) g[x] = f[x,0] (in old file)  for x between 1 and 5000

I am not really sure how the notation for that would be :-(

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have a look at `DumpSave`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for `Save` or `DumpSave`

Here is an example:

```
(*Put some definitions into f*)
ClearAll[f]
f[x_, y_] := f[x, y] = x + y;
Table[f[x, y], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}];

(*are the definitions there?*)
?f

(*Save to file*)
Save["f.m", f]

(*Clear all definitions and check that none remain*)
ClearAll@f
?f

(*Import again*)
Import["f.m"];

?f
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. How would I save only a specific part of when doing

    Save["f.m", f], because all data might be big (because the amount of ram mathematica is using after storing the values is 100gb) - I only need f[1,0] to f[5000,0], which is like 40mb when exporting it as a list.

Comment: you can unset the rest as per this question http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71/clearing-a-specific-definition/76#76

Comment: (clicked too early, 1 sec..)

Comment: I did it by basically doing it the other way around, by creating, saving and importing a new function g with just the needed values: For[i = 1, i <= 5000, i++, g[i] = f[i, 0]]  --  Save["g.m",g]  -- Import[g] That worked, thanks again :-)

Comment: You're welcome.